# BigQuery: how to calculate the frequency of numbers in a table

Tags: count, google-bigquery

I need to calculate how many times occurs one number inside 4 columns of a table.

I used
`COUNT(CASE WHEN column_1 = 1 THEN 1 END)`
And it worked, but just for 1 column and 1 number.

Is it possibile to add all the column_N at once?

If I need to check a lot of numbers (from 1 to 90) how can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the need to do all the columns as once try creating an array.
See below with some sample data.

```
with sample_data as (
    select 1 as id, 1 as col_1, 2 as col_2, 3 as col_3, 4 as col_4 union all 
    select 2, 1, 1, 5, 6 union all 
    select 3, 1, 7, 8, 1
)

select id
    , target
    , count(target) frequency
from sample_data
, UNNEST([col_1 , col_2, col_3, col_4 ]) target
group by id, target
```

If there are unwanted numbers in the columns, example if you're looking for 1-90, but the set also contains 91+, you would apply a where clause to filter out the elements you are not seeking.

As an alternate to this approach you could try to unpivot the columns you are looking to count, however I think this is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach - it handles all columns in in `your_table` except `id` column (assuming you have such). you can add as many columns to be excluded in except list as you need.

```
select id, 
  ( select count(*)
    from unnest(`bqutil.fn.json_extract_values`(to_json_string((
      select as struct * except(id) from unnest([t])
    )))) value
    where value = '1'
  ) as frequency
from your_table t
```

Note: you you wish, instead of excluding columns - you can explicitly list columns you want to participate in the search